# Python list/tuple pop return itself?

Tags: python

This may be rudimentary, but after some searches I couldn't find a way, but `pop()`, `del`, `remove()`.

I have the following python (django) code:

```py
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ..
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('id','user','created_at','title','url','og_image','desc','voters','is_public','updated_at', 'pagevote','pageidenticals',)
        read_only_fields = ('id','user','created_at','voters','is_public','updated_at','pagevote','pageidenticals')
```

Notice the redundancy on the `fields` and `read_only_fields`. The only difference of the two is `title','url','og_image','desc`.

So I just want to reduce the code in `read_only_fields`, like this pseudo code:

```py
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ..
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('id','user','created_at','title','url','og_image','desc','voters','is_public','updated_at', 'pagevote','pageidenticals',)
        read_only_fields = fields.chomps(['title','url','og_image','desc',])
```

Since it's on a class, adding an extra `pop()` like you do in a `def` method is not an option. So, is there a way?

Comment: I'd suggest `fields = read_only_fields + ('title', '...')` instead…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a job for `set` and its difference operator:

```
fields = ('id','user','created_at','title','url','og_image','desc','voters','is_public','updated_at', 'pagevote','pageidenticals',)
read_only_fields = tuple(set(fields)-{'title','url','og_image','desc'}))
print(read_only_fields)
```

Result:

```
('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'pagevote', 'user', 'is_public', 'pageidenticals', 'voters')
```

Just be careful that the order preservation is an implementation detail of CPython, it is not guaranteed to stay the same in the future. So the following alternative might be more appropriate if you absolutely need the order guarantee

```
tuple(x for x in fields if x not in {...})
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `set` provides with a function `symmetric_difference` which basically returns all the items present in given sets, except the items in their intersections.

Try this :

```
fields = ('id','user','created_at','title','url','og_image','desc','voters','is_public','updated_at', 'pagevote','pageidenticals',)

read_only_fields = ('id','user','created_at','voters','is_public','updated_at','pagevote','pageidenticals')

final_output = set(fields).symmetric_difference(set(read_only_fields))

print(final_output)
```

OUTPUT :

```
{'og_image', 'url', 'desc', 'title'}
```